# Resource for journal acceptance rates

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

Does anyone know of a resource or study that compiles statistics about paper acceptance rates in various journals?

I am more interested in biomedical journals, but this would be a good place to list such resources in any scientific field.

Comment: Don't know about a compiled resource, but some journals (too few though) publish rejection/acceptence rates on their websites. If I remember correctly the rejection rates of Nature/Science are 92-93% (2012), and most leading journals in ecology have rejection rates ~80%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few journals/publishers publish statistics about their acceptance rate, but this data is usually rather sparse, and not communicated on the journal webpage itself.

However, publishers often allow researchers in the fields of scientometrics, ethics or psychology access to their (anonymized) database of paper review/acceptance/publication timelines. You can find papers such as [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1552) (and references therein), which then analyze the raw data and publish some statistics about it. We learn, for example, that the acceptance ratio for *Physical Review Letters* in 2012 was at 32%.

Other nuggets of information one can gleam include:

> in the *Europhysics Letters* study Michael Schreiber expressed concern about comparatively high acceptance rates for July-submitted papers

which is always good to know if you happen to work in that field :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few studies on rejection rates in specific areas such as [Atmospheric Sciences](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/2009BAMS2908.1) and [Ecology](http://www.ecobias.org/resources_files/Aarssenetal2008.pdf). In a seminar talk given by Elsevier at my University Library, the indication was that 40-90% rejection rates were not unusual. Typically, high profile journals (usually identified by a high Impact factors) will be at the upper end of the range. I edit a ISI listed journal and we consistently have about a 50% rejection rates. I believe the norm for many fields is in this neighbourhood.

If you are looking for a journal with an exactly known constant rejection rate for a paper you should go for the [JUR](http://www.universalrejection.org/).

Answer (score 3):

On the [Elsevier journal finder service website](http://journalfinder.elsevier.com/) you can find some data about the acceptance rate, but only for journals published by Elsevier (of course). You have to fill the name of your article and add the abstract, than you will find the acceptance rates between the results (together with Impact factor, acceptance time etc.). Unfortunately, you can´t just browse among journals, you will see only the proposed journals which (maybe) suits to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question I have also asked in ResearchGate almost one year ago, and got no replies. The best I could find out is the following Chinese journal database (in Chinese) which provides a series of metrics including some comments on the acceptance rate.

http://www.medsci.cn/sci/

It is, however, quite unclear where the estimates come from. But I think it is still better than naught.